# What condition is false in a multiple conditions if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a multiple if statement in Javascript. I've 3 (or more) conditions, and I wanna doSomething() only if all these 3 conditions are true. If only one of these 3 are false, I wanna doSomethingElse(). I think my code it's right, but my problem is on another level.
What if I wanna know for which condition my statement is false?
E.g.: condition1=true, condition2=true, condition3=false.

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
  doSomething();
} else {
  doSomethingElse();
};
```

I've thought that I can put another if statement in the else part.

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
  doSomething();
} else {
  if (condition1 == false) {
    doWhatIDoWhenC1isFalse();
  };
};
```

Is this the right way? Is there any other way to do this? Maybe faster way!
Thank for your help, and be nice to me, it's my second day on Javascript :)

Comment: Sorry, It's little unclear... You want to use a function if cond1,cond2 are true and cond3 is false otherwise use another function?

Comment: Yes, you are right, you will have to test for the "interesting" condition manually. There is no other way to know.

Comment: you could create an array with al the "conditions" and with that array take out only the ones that are false, but if you are talking of 3 or so conditions the way that you expressed it is the fastest...

Comment: if all conditions are false you execute `doWhatIDoWhenC1isFalse` while you want to know if only one is false

Comment: You can try.... `elseif (condition1 + condition2 + condition3 == 2)` it should work but... not very logical

Comment: Bhojendra the condition3 = false was only an example! I just wanna know what to do if one or multiple conditions are false (and how to check WHAT condition is false).
Thank syazdani for the rapid answer!

Comment: if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) { doSomething(); return;}
dosomethingElse()

Comment: Is this a question just out of curiosity, or do you have a specific use-case? It would be interesting to know, why/how you're going to use this.

Comment: Why don't you just output each condition in console and see which is which?

Comment: pankajparkar, I'm writing a quiz-site, and this is just a piece of code that I need to save a question. 
If "answer" is empty, than send a notification "You can't leave your answer empty!" and so on :)

Comment: You could convert the conditions to byte values (0 = false, 1, 2, 4 = true) and sum the conditions and use the sum for example to call a function (object's method) or as an array index.

Comment: @Teemu This looks a nice way.. Can you implement it?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes [Array](http://jsfiddle.net/55pwshrg/) and [Object](http://jsfiddle.net/55pwshrg/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the conditions are mutually exclusive, you can just use an `else if` without nesting.

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
    doSomething();
} else if (!condition1) {
    doWhatIDoWhenC1isFalse();
}
// add more else-if conditions as needed
```

If only one of your conditions can be false at a time (or if you don't care when two of them are false) then you can just have three else-if clauses and check each condition individually. If you do need to treat the cases where two conditions are false separately, you'll need an else-if for each combination. Pay close attention to the order you list them in if that's the case. The cases where you check if two conditions are both false should come before the cases where you only check one condition.

Comment: only one of the false condition may also be condition2, or condition3, then...?

Comment: @BhojendraSah then add more else if as it says in the comment or you can just output each condition in the console and see which is true and which is false

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
  doSomething();
}else if (!condition1){
  doWhatIDoWhenC1isFalse();
}else if (!condition2){
  doWhatIDoWhenC2isFalse();
}else{
  doWhatIDoWhenC3isFalse();
}
```

You have to do something along the lines of this. No way to cleanly get which expression that failed.

Answer (score 0):

You may go this way if you want if any one of the condition is false:

```
if ((!condition1 && condition2 && condition3)||
   (condition1 && !condition2 && condition3)||
   (condition1 && condition2 && !condition3)) 
{
   doSomethingElse();      
} else {
  doSomething();
};
```

Comment: What if the 3 are true ?

Comment: How does this answer "What if I wanna know for which condition my statement is false?" ?

Comment: @BhojendraSah Oh right, I didn't notice you inverted doSomething and doSomethingElse, my bad

Answer (score 0):

It can be:

```
var x = []; /* an array that will take expressions number that result true */

if(condition1) x.push(1);
if(condition2) x.push(2);
if(condition3) x.push(3);


if( x.length == 2 ){ /* if two conditions got true */
    doThingForTwoTrue();
}
if( x.length == 3 ){ /* if three conditions got true */
    doThingForThreeTrue();
}
if( x.indexOf(1) !== -1 ){ /* if condition1 got true */
    doThingOne();
}
```