# Is there any way to findout the truth value in an if condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario like this

```
var a,b;
if(a > 0 || b > 0){
  var truthValue = // The value which was executed as true in the if condition either a or b
}
```

Now how do i identify which value is executed as true. I can write a separate if condition for both but in the process of minimizing the LOC i am trying this way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just use an if else condition, it will tell you a or b is greater than 0,also check both conditions are true case,false case

Comment: And what if both conditions are true? You will choose first or higher?

Comment: What if both of them are greater than 0?

Comment: A possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27968511/1169519 ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```js
var truth, a=11, b=0;
if((truth = a) > 0 || (truth = b) > 0){
  document.write(truth + "<br>")
}

var a=0, b=22;
if((truth = a) > 0 || (truth = b) > 0){
  document.write(truth + "<br>")
}
```

Comment: what happens when a and b are true ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: the first one wins.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a,b;
a =1;
b=2;
if(((a > 0)? (truthValue =a) : false) || ((b > 0)? (truthValue =b) : false)){
  alert(truthValue);
}
```